# How do I share my netlogo model with a collaborator without revealing or sending the actual code?

Tags: netlogo

My supervisor has asked me to share the code of my netlogo model with another potential collaborator but I am vary of IP. This is my code and I do not want to share it without publishing it first. But I can not say no to him either. How do I share my netlogo model in a way that it allows the collaborator to use the model's GUI but not access the code itself?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to share NetLogo models without sharing the code. Even NetLogo web allows access to the code. Have you considered taking a different approach and using github or similar so that it is clear that the code is yours?

Comment: Thanks @JenB yes I did consider, I am just not comfortable sharing it on any repo before publishing. Can I also ask a second question here? I don't know if this was asked before (I searched for two hours):

1) is it possible to pass a variable length of arguments to a function in netlogo?
2) How to use runresult to call a function within a function, wherein both functions take multiple aruguments?

Comment: I am procrastinating - so I answer first. Other people are around. It is definitely possible but will require something that needs a real question,  preferably with example input and output. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539334/pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-netlogo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522535/attempting-to-trick-netlogo-into-executing-a-function-passed-as-an-argument (you should be using the solutions that aren't mine)

Answer (score 3):

There is another option--The NetLogo Obfuscator:
http://bert.stuy.edu/pbrooks/netlogo/obfuscator/NO_main.py

It takes your NetLogo file and turns it into a new one that is much harder to read but still works.